# Query pages based on tags

Tags: pages, query, tags

On a site that I'm working on I've added the ability to tag pages. These tags should then be used in a query to retrieve all associated pages of a tag.

In my functions file -

```
// Add tag support to Pages
function tags_support_all() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
}
function tags_support_query($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->get('tag')) $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
}
add_action('init', 'tags_support_all');
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

Query -

```
$tag = get_query_var('tag');
$articles = new WP_Query( array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tag' => $tag,
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

For some reason it doesn't match my pages agains the tags. I can see that the tags are being added under my tags collection in the admin panel, but supposedly there's a setting missing that makes WP only look for matching posts.

To answer birgie's question, I get this result when using printf -

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (5) ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
```

Comment: What's the output of  `printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', $articles->request ); ` ?

Comment: based on your edit, your query appears correct. do the pages have a `date` meta key associated with them?

Comment: Milo, thanks for pointing that out. I obviously missed removing this... Works without the sort order!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't mentioned post_type here and by default `post_type` is `'post'` and hence it is  missing the pages,

add the below in your query

`'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' )`

Like this

```
$articles = new WP_Query( array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tag' => $tag,
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I've already tried this and it doesn't give me any results. This shouldn't be necessary however after initiating the tags_support_query function in my previous code.